# Writing pandas data frame to csv but no space between columns- sep'\t' argument is ignored in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a problem and found many related questions asked here and read them all, but still can`t solve it. So far I didn't get any answer.

I have two files one is .csv and the other is .xlsx. They have a different number of rows and columns.  I would like to merge these two according to filenames. Very simplified the two files look like as follows;

The csv file;

[image]

the excel file;

[image]

First i converted them  to panda data frame;

```
import pandas as pd
import csv,xlrd

df1 = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv')
df2=pd.read_excel(myexcel.xlsx', sheetname=0)
```

To merge the two files on the same column I remove the white space in column names in df2 using the first line below and, then I merge them and print the merged data frame in csv file.

```
df2.columns=df2.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
df=pd.merge(df1, df2, on="filename")
df.to_csv('myfolder \\merged_file.csv', sep="\t ")
```

When I check my folder, I see merged_file.csv exists but when I opened it there is no space between columns and values. I want to see nice normal csv or excel look, like my example files above. Just to make sure I tried everything, I also converted the Excel file to a csv file and then merged two csv but still merged data is written without spaces. Again, the above files are very simplified, but my real merged data look like this;

[image]

Comment: You don't need to rename the columns - you can specify a different column name to merge on for each dataframe: `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on="filename", right_on="file name")`

Comment: Thank you muzzyq, I applied your suggestion but it still writes the merged data without space all in the first column in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, figured it out. I am putting the answer here just in case if anyone else also manages the same mistake as me. Just remove the sep="\t"  and use below line instead;

```
df.to_csv('myfolder \\merged_file.csv')
```

Just realized the two csv files were comma separated and using tab delimiter for merge didn`t work.